# Running RHEL7 images on Google Kubernetes Engine

Tags: image, containers, openshift, google-kubernetes-engine, rhel7

In terms of best practices and possibly future issues, would there be any issue running RHEL7 base images on GKE in production?

Answer (score 1):

GKE doesn’t support RHEL7.

GKE offers the following node image options for your cluster:
Container-Optimized OS from Google,
Ubuntu,
Container-Optimized OS with containerd (cos_containerd),
Ubuntu with containerd (ubuntu_containerd).

Any image family updates or addition will post on this page:

https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/concepts/node-images